# How do you get StringBuilder's ToString method to not escape the escape characters in a string?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Thanks to NgM I am using StringBuilder in .NET 3.5 to find and escape special chars.  However, when I use the ToString method, it escapes the escape chars which then makes the previous exercise useless.  Anyone know how to get around that?

Here is the code:

```
    private String ParseAndEscapeSpecialChars(String input)
    {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);
        String output;
        String specialChars = @"([-\]\[<>\?\*\\\""/\|\~\(\)\#/=><+\%&\^\'])";
        Regex expression = new Regex(specialChars);

        if (expression.IsMatch(input))
        {
            sBuilder.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
            sBuilder.Replace(@"'", @"\'");                
        }

        output = sBuilder.ToString();
        return output;
    }
```

Here are the results from debug:

```
input       "005 - SomeCompany's/OtherCompany's Support Center"
sBuilder    {005 - SomeCompany\'s/OtherCompany\'s Support Center}
output      "005 - SomeCompany\\'s/OtherCompany\\'s Support Center"
```

Comment: I also tried @sBuilder.ToString() and saw the same issue.

Comment: Where are you seeing this output? Console? Winforms label? Debugger?

Comment: Looking at the code you shouldn't have patterns like ...\\'... in the output. Is there a chance that you look at the output under debugger (that would escape slash for presentation purpose) as opposed to e.g. `Console.Write(output)` ?

Answer (score 7):

`StringBuilder` doesn't escape characters. It does *nothing* special or clever. Dollars to doughnuts you're just seeing this in the debugger, which *does* show you an escaped version.

Comment: Thanks for the info, seems to be working correctly, just debug is adding the escape chars.  I'm using the string to build an SQL query, guess I need to find out what works in SQL to escape '

Comment: @mattg: No, you don't. You shouldn't be putting values into your SQL in the first place. Use a parameterized query instead - that way you don't need to do escaping at all, and you don't need to worry about SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4):

You say your results are from debug. If by that you mean the debugger itself, by examining the string contents by hovering over the variable or putting it on a watch list in VS then the debugger display will escape the slashes in its windows/tooltips. However if you actually output the string in your code you will see the escaping is not there - it's just a debugger "feature".

Try

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(myOutputVariable);
```

and look in the output window to see the "real" contents.